# Vue v-for list does not update after data changed

Tags: vuejs2, updates, v-for

The idea is simple:
The Vue instance loads groups from an API.
This groups are shown using a v-for syntax.

The groupdata is formatted properly, and added to app.groups using .push function, which should update the v-for list.

However, the v-for list will not update.

When I change v-for="group in groups" (loaded externally) to v-for="group in people" (already in the app), it does give output.

HTML

```
   <div id="app" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Realtime Socket Chat</div>
                <div class="panel-body" v-if="dataReady" v-for="group in groups"> @{{ group.name }}
                    <a v-bind:href="group.link" class="pull-right">
                        <div class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                            Join
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Vue

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        groups: [],
        people: [{name: 'hi'}, {name: 'lol'}]
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.load()
    },
    methods: {
        load: function() {
            axios.get('http://example.com/groups')
                .then(function (response) {

                console.log(response.data.groups);

                response.data.groups.forEach(function(group) {
                    app.groups.push(group);
                });

                // app.groups.forEach(function (group) {
                //    group.link = '/g/' + group.id + '/join';
                // });
                // console.log(response.data.groups);

                console.log(this.groups); //outputs [{...}, {...}] so this.groups is good
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                this.errors.push(error);
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }

});
```

API

{

"groups": [
    {

```
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Photography Chat",
  "created_at": "2017-11-26 08:50:16",
  "updated_at": "2017-11-26 08:50:16"
},

{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Media Chat",
  "created_at": "2017-11-26 08:50:16",
  "updated_at": "2017-11-26 08:50:16"
}
```

]

}

Comment: Update: adding :key="group.id" did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fact I left out in the question (because I assumed it would not matter) was that I am working within the Laravel framework, Laravel automatically imports Vuejs within main.js. Which does not play nice when Vue is loaded in additionally. I removed main.js and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `app` is undefined when your `load` function is executed. So, using ES6 arrow function syntax, your `load` function should look like this:

```
load: function() {
  axios.get('http://example.com/groups')
    .then(response => {    
      let groups = response.data.groups || []

      groups.forEach(group => {
        this.groups.push(group)
      })

      console.log(this.groups)

    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.errors.push(error)
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: This is also a working way to push the data in app.groups or this.groups, however this also does not update the Vue view. More specifically, only data that is in the Vue instance already gets loaded. Even when I type the command "app.groups.push({name: "Another Group"}];" the new group gets pushed to app.groups, however the view is not updated. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Ok, could you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: The problem was that Vue was loaded due to an src which I myself included, after which the Vue app was initialized, however, after that Vue was loaded again because Laravel loads it by default. This second loading of the Vue library made the first Vue app crash.